# Rename data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with name df. I would like to save it in a file with a better name. 
I would like to be able to do this:

```
df = ...

rename.data.frame(df, "gdp_2001_2014") 

# Now the data.frame has a new name and can be used as normal:
gdp_2001_2014$y = 0

# And it can be saved with a nice name:
save(gdp_2001_2014, file=".\\datafile.Rdata")
```

The name is important of the following reason: when you load data the name follows automatically:

```
load(".\\datafile.Rdata")

summary(gdp_2001_2014)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
## to re-name the data frame
gdp_2001_2014 <- df
## remove data frame 'df'
rm(df)                            
## write new data frame to file
write.table(gdp_2001_2014, file = "yourPath.Rdata")
```

Depending on the data, you could also use `write.csv` or `writeLines` and others.

Comment: This creates a copy of the data frame, not identical to renaming

Comment: R does *copy-on-modify*. There's no copy being made just by assignment. @RichardScriven, maybe you can do `rm(df)` following that. That'd be equivalent of what the OP calls 'renaming', isn't it?

Comment: I think rm(df); gc() is better. As far as I understand it, rm will not disallocate memory.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in 1 call

```
write.csv(df,file="gdp_2001_2014.csv",row.names=FALSE)
#row.names=FALSE if you don't want the row index
```

Comment: This saves the data to ``.csv`` and does not keep the dataframe. If you change this method to save a dataframe, the file name will be as you specify, but the dataframe itself will still be named ``df``.

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenient way to do this in the [usethis](https://usethis.r-lib.org/) package. This helper method is called [`use_data`](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/use_data.html).

I'm reusing below the example proposed by @Rich Scriven.

```
## to re-name the data frame
gdp_2001_2014 <- df
## remove data frame 'df'
rm(df)                            
## write new data frame to file
usethis::use_data(gdp_2001_2014, overwrite = TRUE)
```