# rename data frame to rotating variable

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

My question is similar to the one here ([Rename data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407315/rename-data-frame)), but I am trying to rename it based on a rotating variable name.

```
df2<-data.frame(a=seq(1:5),b=c(1:10), c=c(11:20))
df2$a = c('alpha', 'alpha','alpha', 'beta', 'beta', 'gamma', 'beta','alpha',    'alpha','alpha')

variables<- c('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')

for (var in variables) {
alpha<- df2
beta<- df2
gamma<- df2
}
```

Instead of having the three lines to create a copy of df2 named alpha, beta, gamma I want to have one line to create the copy of df2, so have

```
var <- df2
```

inside the loop, and as var rotates with the loop, so after its three runs through the loop I would have alpha,beta,gamma as above as it goes through the loop. 
My real purpose is I am using the same data frame and then doing a number of calculations on it, and then want to name the resulting data frame after the variable that is currently being used in the loop.

I know that in bash I would do data_${var} and it would result with data_alpha, data_beta, data_gamma, but what about in R?

Any one know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  Can you explain or provide the desired result(s) from `df2`  Are you looking for something like `list2env(split(df2, df2$a), .GlobalEnv)` ?  This splits `df2` by `df$a` and then assigns the variables `alpha` `beta` and `gamma` to the global environment

Comment: This is why data structures exist. Put your data frames in a list, and then the "names" of each data frame can be easily manipulated programmatically.

Comment: I just realized I answered that question in the link.  That was one of my first answers and now that I look back, it's not very good :)

Answer (score 1):

This is [FAQ 7.21](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f).  The most important part of that answer is where it says not to do this.

What would be better is to use a list and assign your copies into the list:

```
variables<- c('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')

mydfs <- list()

for (var in variables) {
  mydfs[[var]] <- df2
}
```

Or for just the above:

```
mydfs <- rep( list(df2), length(variables) )
names(mydfs) <- variables
```

Then additional processing can be done using `lapply`, `sapply` or similar functions.

Comment: Seconding the suggestion not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `assign(var, df2)`.